# Classification Algorithm which can take predefined weights for attributes as input

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, classification

I have 20 attributes and one target feature. All the attributes are binary(present or not present) and the target feature is multinomial(5 classes).

But for each instance, apart from the presence of some attributes, I also have the information that how much effect(scale 1-5) did each present attribute have on the target feature.

How do I make use of this extra information that I have, and build a classification model that helps in better prediction for the test classes.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the weights as the features, instead of binary presence indicator? You can code the lack of presence as a 0 on the continuous scale.

EDIT:

The classifier you choose to use will learn optimal weights on the features in training to separate the classes... thus I don't believe there's any better you can do if you do *not* have access to test weights. Essentially a linear classifier is learning a rule of the form:

c_i = sgn(w . x_i)

You're saying you have access to weights, but without an example of what the data look like, and an explanation of where the weights come from, I'd have to say I don't see how you'd use them (or even why you'd want to---is standard classification with binary features not working well enough?)

Comment: We cannot use these values as features as we do not know these weights for the test(prediction) data, as we do not know how much would these attributes affect the target feature in the unseen data. All we know is whether these attributes are present or absent.

Can you please suggest some other technique to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

This clearly depends on the actual algorithms that you are using.

For decision trees, the information is useless. They are meant to learn which attributes have how much effect.

Similarly, support vector machines will learn the best linear split, so any kind of weight will disappear since the SVM already learns this automatically.

However, if you are doing NN classification, just scale the attributes as desired, to emphasize differences in the influential attributes.

Sorry, you need to look at other algorithms yourself. There are just too many.

Comment: Actually we are not aware of any influential attributes as such, but for each training instance the influence might be different for each attribute. Attribute A might affect more in instance one, but might affect less in instance two and so on.

I understand that Nearest Neighbour can take care of this, by including these weights as a part of the distance metric that we come up with.

Can you please suggest some other algorithms that can include these weights, as nearest negihbour is difficult to scale in terms of memory(while training) and time as well(while prediction).

Comment: Sorry i do not think that we can include that in the metric as we do not know the weights for the attributes in the unseen data.

Comment: Further we do not even have one fixed influence of each attribute. 
Please suggest how can we use this information...

Answer (score 0):

Use the knowledge as prior over the weight of features. You can actually compute the posterior estimation out of the data and then have the final model